# How do I form a string of 5 elements in a assembly array

Tags: arrays, assembly, io, x86

I currently have a array of 25 numbers. I want to create a string of 5 numbers and then output them. Then get 5 more numbers and output the string and so on.... So basically a 5x5 grid of the array numbers. My issue is that I am not sure how to get a number out of the array, then put it on the string. Loop 5x and then output.

x86 Assembly. Using WORDs

Here is my code:

### VARIABLES

```
    inputGridArray WORD MAXNBRS DUP (?)
    grid_Rows WORD ?
    grid_Cols WORD ?
    gridSize WORD ?
    temp WORD ?
    empty WORD ?
    prompt BYTE 0, 0
    string BYTE 40 DUP (0)
```

### MACRO

```
printArray  MACRO array_name, size_array
        LOCAL PRINT_ARRAY, PRINT_ROW, NEXT_ROW, END_PRINT_LOOP

        lea ebx, array_name
        mov cx, 0
        mov temp, 0
        PRINT_ARRAY:
            cmp cx, grid_Cols
            je END_PRINT_LOOP
            PRINT_ROW:
                mov ax, temp
                cmp ax, grid_Rows
                je NEXT_ROW

                ;I need to construct a string maybe, to be able to put the array into a grid shape
                outputW WORD PTR [ebx]
                add ebx, 2
                inc temp
                jmp PRINT_ROW

                NEXT_ROW:
                    inc cx
                    mov temp, 0
                    jmp PRINT_ARRAY
        END_PRINT_LOOP:
    ENDM
```

Comment: Why would you store `grid_Rows` in memory, when it's an assemble-time constant?  And why would you keep `temp` in memory instead of in a register?  The whole point of registers is to hold temporary values.

Comment: Anyway, indexing a multidimensional array just means you have to do the address math yourself.  `array[i*5 + j]`, since you have 5 columns.  Just look at C compiler output for a multidimensional array.  e.g. [`int A[5][5]; int foo(int i, int j){ return A[i][j]; }`](https://godbolt.org/g/SZpqUh) (on godbolt with -m32 -fno-omit-frame-pointer.  Change the array type to `short` if you want it to be even more like your problem.

Comment: I don't like macros like this... why don't you rather turn it into procedure and do a `call` to it. This macro takes array address as argument, but size of array takes from global variables. It would either make more sense to take all input as arguments for macro, or create procedure and give it arguments in registers. And macro means, that by every usage in code you copy the code there, so if you would use this like 30 times, it would compile into 30x this code (it's OK with short macros). With call->procedure way you have the code in binary only once.